# How do I fade html in after jquery animation is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html fades in right away, and I want it to fade in after the animation is completed. It is an image that rotates to the top of the screen, then I would like the rest to fade in. How would I get that to work?

Here is what I want to fade in after the animation is done:

```
$('header, .main').fadeIn(2000);
```

Here is the complete jQuery:

```
  $( '.dimg-main' ).animate({ 
      top: "-=38%", 
      borderSpacing: -360 
  },{
      step: function(now) {
          $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
          $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
          $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      },
      duration:4000,
  }),
  $('header, main').fadeIn(2000);
```

css:

```
header, main{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the [complete callback function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$( '.dimg-main' ).animate({ 
  top: "-=38%", 
  borderSpacing: -360 
},{
  step: function(now) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
  },
  duration:4000,
  complete: function(){
        $('header, main').fadeIn(2000);
  }
});
```